# Things we can do with VPS Packages

Tags: marketing, vps, features

I am planning for purchase of VPS Package. Beside Webspace hosting, what other features can we provide to our customers?

Comment: Managed or unmanaged? If unmanaged, be sure to do some research first. You won't be the first who think that firewalls are superfluous and soon rooted afterwards.

Comment: Its managed one

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking of renting a VPS to resell web hosting but you're not sure what else to do with it, **you'd probably be better off renting a "reseller hosting account"** from someone like [Hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/resellers.shtml).

A reseller account allows you to offer web, email, and database hosting to your customers without needing to learn how to configure and maintain a web server. Your customers get a control panel and one-click app installers for things like WordPress, and you often get features like a billing system, white-label branding (with your logo), and outsourced technical support.

Comment: +1 ... a cPanel reseller account includes features you can provide customers - a VPS at a similar price point wouldn't even include enough memory to run cPanel.

Comment: I do have cPanel in my VPS and i can even do white label branding with my logo but about billing system its not there

Comment: I would consider switching your VPS account to a reseller one. Unless you want to serve a particular application that needs the freedom a VPS offers, it sounds like a reseller account would serve you better.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide them with installed software such as Wordpress, Drupal, phpBB, Joomla, MediaWiki etc. Just have a look at webhosting companies to see what they offer.

Answer (score 0):

A VPS allows for full control of the server. If customers need a custom solution like Varnish HTTP caching, or memcached you can provide this. This also allows you to control what version of PHP is installed along with the web server. So if you wanted nginx instead of Apache you could do this.

Simply, a VPS provides more control and additional capacity.

Answer (score 0):

With a VPS you can provide your customers security and peace of mind that they are not squeezed on a server with a 1000 other sites.

You can run any packages you want like APC for caching, configure a [ghetto CDN](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/), give them real shell access, a torrent tracker (no copyright violations please), and IRC server.

The list goes on.  A VPS is like having your own dedicated server except it doesn't cost as much and doesn't provide the same performance.  If your in the web industry with clients it will also show your clients that you provide a better quality of service.

Answer (score 0):

You could also host a multiplayer game server, like a Minecraft server for example, but it needs a lot of ressources, it depend on the hardware that you have.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally looking at a VPS after moving from a Helm Reseller package but quickly realised that at this stage in our business, it was too much too soon and just went for a CPanel reseller package that came with a free licence for WHMCS and we haven't looked back.

In a couple of years when we outgrow this solution a VPS will be the next step but until then we are happy having someone else deal with all the complicated Linux stuff so we can get on and sell hosting to our clients.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage to a VPS is that you decide what goes on it. For example, if you don't want to use apache... install something else. If you want Ruby (or another language that is not always on shared hosting) then install it!